# How to report a non-fatal exception with Firebase crash on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

How to report on iOS a non-fatal exception using Firebase Crash Reporting? In Android, we can do something like this:

```
 FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Firebase non-fatal error on Android"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/#key_capabilities), you can only report *fatal* errors on iOS at this time.

Comment: At the time when you posted this, it was true but things are changed, see this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#log-excepts

Answer (score 25):

### You can now log non-fatal exceptions in Firebase Crashlytics

The accepted answer is therefore no longer correct. Non-fatal exceptions can be logged with the following Firebase Crashlytics method:

```
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
```

From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#log_non-fatal_exceptions):

> This allows you to record a non-fatal event, described by an NSError object. These events will be grouped and displayed similarly to crashes. Keep in mind that this method can be expensive. Also, the total number of NSErrors that can be recorded during your app's life-cycle is limited by a fixed-size circular buffer. If the buffer is overrun, the oldest data is dropped. Errors are relayed to Crashlytics on a subsequent launch of your application.

---

**Example usage:**

```
let userInfo: [String: String] = [
    "deviceId": "someDeviceId",
    "localizedDescription": yourException.localizedDescription,
    "anotherKey": "anotherValue"
]

let domain = "METHOD: some/domain/that/just/had-an-exception"
let code = 404

let error = NSError(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: userInfo)

Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
```

Where `domain` is some pretty identifier for use in Firebase (e.g. method + request path), `code` is the status code of the exception (a 404 here), and `userInfo` additional data are converted to key-value pairs and displayed in the keys/logs section within an individual issue.

*Note: Logged errors are grouped by the NSError `domain` and `code` (unlike fatals, which are grouped in Firebase by their stack trace).*

---

**Example output in Firebase `Console > Crashlytics`:**

[image: Example output showing non-fatal exceptions in Firebase Crashlytics console]

**Issue details page in the console (showing `userInfo` key-value pairs):**

[image: Example details view of a non-fatal exception issue in the Firebase Crashlytics console (showing userInfo key-value pairs)]

Answer (score 6):

Jen's answer is correct. There are a few alternatives you can consider, though:

1. Log a Firebase Analytics event. While this won't give you all the stack tracey goodness you get from Firebase Crash Reporting, you can at least keep track of how often a particular exception is happening over time.
2. Use the `FIRCrashMessage()` method to make note of any errors that occur in your app. You will only see these log methods in crash reports that end up getting reported to Firebase Crash Reporting, but given that errors often lead to crashes, this isn't such a bad idea.
3. Try Crashlytics. They have a [`reportError()`](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html) method that's specifically designed for reporting non-fatal errors. It's fine to use Crashlytics for your crash reporting while continuing to use other features of Firebase within your app -- it's all the same parent company these days. :)